# LibGDX - How to have a lower resolution without blurring the pixels

Tags: java, libgdx, pixel, screen-resolution

On very old games, they were limited to smaller resolutions. I want mine to be like this, but when I make the resolution smaller it blurs the pixels. Is there any way to make it so it doesn't blur it but still make it smaller? If you don't know what I mean, here's a link to a game on itch.io which has exactly what I want: http://ansdor.itch.io/slipstream-demo (You don't have to actually download it, you can just watch the video.

Comment: Can't use the link right now but I can think of 2 ways (not sure which you want): draw to a smaller portion of the screen (probably not what you want) or use `TextureFilter.NEAREST` (or similar, I don't know libgdx that well) - the keyword would be mipmapping.

Comment: @Thomas Mip mapping doesn't apply when using nearest filtering.

Comment: @Thomas I've looked up mipmapping in LibGDX and it seems that it's only for how a particular texture is drawn, not the entire screen; in other words you can do mipmapping on a texture but not the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in my comment mipmapping should help. It's about how a pixel's color is determined by the texture that is applied so on the inside of a quad (that's what you're probably using) it should be ok while the edges might be subject to antialiasing etc. - which you should be able to turn off.

Another thing you could do is to render the entire scene to a texture of the desired dimensions (e.g. 320 x 240 pixels) and then render that texture to the screen while employing mipmapping.